# How to write \slashed, \mathcal and \mathring at the same time?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, mathcal

I need to write something like `\slashed{\mathcal{\mathring{S}}}`. I tried to write it in several orders, but none of them gave me the wanted result. I found out that I have to write `\slashed{\mathcal{S}}` to get correct result, but I wasn't successful in adding `\mathring` to it. I use package "slashed" for `\slashed{S}`. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{slashed}

\begin{document}
$\slashed{\mathcal{S}}$
%$\slashed{\mathring{\mathcal{S}}}$
$\mathring{\slashed{\mathcal{S}}}$
\end{document}
```

The second order doesn't work, I get 3 errors on it, that suggest that I have forgotten to type `}` or so, but I think it is just a consequence of some other error, maybe wrong order. Sorry, I am not very experienced in understanding errors like this.

Comment: You should do `\mathring{\mathcal{S}}` in any case. The reverse is wrong and if it works is just by chance.

Comment: OK, thank you. You are right, \mathcal{\mathring{S}} doesn't work, the result is just S with some strange lines at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the appearance to be *exactly* like `\slashed`, you can use the following hack that actually prints the character twice on top of itself: once with the ring, and once with the slash.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{slashed,mathtools}

\newcommand{\slashedring}[1]{\slashed{#1}\mathllap{\mathring{#1}}}

\begin{document}

$\slashed{\mathcal{S}} \slashedring{\mathcal{S}} \mathring{\mathcal{S}}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the example]

Comment: This works very nicely, the only thing I don't like about it is that my \slashedring{S} looks thick compared to the other \slashed{S} and \mathring{S}. That might be confusing since it is supposed to be four-vector and only normal (three-) vectors are usually written as bold.

Comment: I think it's only when viewed on screen (at small scale), it should look good when printed.

Answer (score 5):

`\slashed` really only works with single glyphs, may be you could use the `cancel` package for your purposes:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{slashed,cancel}

\begin{document}

\(  \mathcal S + \slashed{\mathcal S} + \cancel{\mathcal S} \)

\( \mathring{\mathcal S} + \mathring{\slashed{\mathcal S}} +
\cancel{\mathring{\mathcal S}} + \cancel{\mathring{\mathcal S}\mkern1mu} \)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If there's no other way, I will have to use that package. But that would be very unpleasant, since the slashes of \slashed and \cancel have different slopes, and I used in my whole document the "slashed" version...

Comment: what happens with `\slashed{\mathring{\mathcal S}}` or isn't that arrangement possible?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Please, see the edited question or try to run the code. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for edit.  i'm stuck away from a tex system because of snow, so i can't check at the moment.

Comment: @Suzie If you go for this solution you can always remove the "slashed" package and add `\newcommand{\slashed}[1]{\cancel{#1}}` to make everything look the same without having to switch everywhere :)

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't work good (but neither `slashed` does) for all calligraphic letters, but for the S it seems good:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{slashed}

\newcommand{\slashedring}[1]{{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\mathring{\mathcal{#1}}$\cr
    \hidewidth\raisebox{.2ex}{/}\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}}

\begin{document}
$\slashed{\mathcal{S}}$
$\slashedring{S}\slashedring{R}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If needed also in subscripts/superscripts, the simplest thing is to do

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\slashedring}[1]{\text{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\mathring{\mathcal{#1}}$\cr
    \hidewidth\raisebox{.2ex}{/}\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in script or scriptscript sizes.

Comment: @wipet It's very easy to add it, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is `\slashring[h-offset]{letter}` using stacks.  It is set up to work in all mathstyles, though the horizontal offset should be specified in a unit that scales with the local mathstyle such as `\LMpt` or `\LMex` provided by the `scalerel` package.  The `-2.3\LMpt` in the definition specifies the vertical offset of the `\mathring` and can be altered to suit.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\newcommand\slashring[2][.4\LMex]{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackinset{c}{#1}{t}{-2.3\LMpt}{\SavedStyle\mathring{}}{%
    \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\SavedStyle/}{\SavedStyle\mathcal{#2}}}}}}
\begin{document}
$\slashring{S} \slashring[0pt]{P}\slashring[2.5\LMpt]{J}$\par
$\scriptstyle\slashring{S} \slashring[0pt]{P}\slashring[2.5\LMpt]{J}$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle\slashring{S} \slashring[0pt]{P}\slashring[2.5\LMpt]{J}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wanted to avoid having to type in the customized horizontal offset for each letter, the "kerns" could be pretabulated:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\newcommand\SlashRing[2]{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackinset{c}{#1}{t}{-2.3\LMpt}{\SavedStyle\mathring{}}{%
    \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\SavedStyle/}{\SavedStyle\mathcal{#2}}}}}}
\newcommand\slashring[1]{%
  \def\HorizontalOffset{.4\LMex}%
  \ifx P#1\def\Horizontaloffset{0pt}\else
  \ifx J#1\def\Horizontaloffset{2.5\LMpt}\else
  \fi\fi%
  \SlashRing{\HorizontalOffset}{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
                  $\slashring{S} \slashring{P} \slashring{J}$\par
      $\scriptstyle\slashring{S} \slashring{P} \slashring{J}$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle\slashring{S} \slashring{P} \slashring{J}$
\end{document}
```